# How to embed third party code in a Java EE Environment where EJB3 is used

Tags: java, thread-safety, ejb

I am writing a web application which runs on a GlassFish 2.1.1. This application contains actually only one stateless session bean, which uses classes from a third party lib. The instances of this classes are services which create a lot of self managed threads during the runtime. I have read in the EJB Restrictions that creating threads in EJB's is not a good idea.

I am pretty new to Java EE and EJB but I am wondering how it is possible to use third party libs which are not developed for EJB in a EJB environment. I would like to know how i can embed this third party service which is simple a singleton in my Java EE application using EJB in a save way.

The only idea I have is to instantiate the service in a servlet and pass the instance by method call to the EJBs. Would this be a better way?

thanks in advance
Alex

A few more details about my project:

The library which i have to use is certainly not made for a EJB Container. However, i have no choise. I also have changed my desing a bit which i try to explain briefly.
The main purpose of my webapplication is to process jobs. Basicly it is similar to the CI server hudson. The jobs are something else then build tasks. However, the jobs can be started over web GUI. If the user push the start button only a entry with a state is insert in a database table. The database table is used as execution queue. A nother bean, a TimerBean will check the database periodically and call an enginge which is my thridparty lib to process this job. The job processing is decoupled of the Client and no transactions are needed.

1. Does it keep state between method calls?
    Yes, i have to keep the current job in order to cancel the execution. I have solved this with a static variable. I know this is also something i shouldn't do in EJBs but the EJB will never be used for clustering.
2. Does it access files, open connections?
   The thirdparty library reads and writes files.
3. Does it synchronize threads using shared resources, like class
   variables? I don't know the internals of the thirdparty library but i suppose, Yes!

Comment: Servlet method probalby will not solve your problem, but first you would have to find out if you have a problem at all ;). Do you use transactions in your stateless EJB?

Comment: Actually i have no problem at all, it is working. I am just afraid of unexpected behaviour during runtime due to this EJB restriction. I don't use transactions in the stateless EJB.

Answer (score 0):

> The instances of this classes are services which create a lot of self managed threads during the runtime

Seeing this, a big red alert lamp should go off in your head. This only shows that your library is probably not a good candidate for use with EJB and you should know **thoroughly** how it works before you proceed with integrating it.

Some other questions you might want to ask:

1. Does it keep state between method calls?
2. Does it access files, open connections?
3. Does it synchronize threads using shared resources, like class variables?

Since your library probably makes an attempt to scale itself to the environment, one precautionary step might be making sure it's accessed through a singleton EJB (it would at least increase the chance of running correctly on a single VM). To achieve this on GF 2.1 you need to set it in `sun-ejb-jar.xml`:

```xml
<ejb>
    <ejb-name>MyEJB</ejb-name>
    <jndi-name>ejb/MyEJB</jndi-name>
    <bean-pool>
        <steady-pool-size>1</steady-pool-size>
        <max-pool-size>1</max-pool-size>
    </bean-pool>
</ejb>
```

You could ininialize your library in a `@PostConstruct` method of `MyEJB`, no need to use a special servlet for it.

It's just a sketch of the solution, everything depends on how the library really works.

Comment: Ok, I see, i schuld not underestimate the restrictions. Unfortunately, I have no other posibility. I have to use this library in a EJB. This means i have to find a solution which is acceptable for the EJB Container. For more details see new entry.

Comment: It is surely possible to integrate it, but with caution and perhaps with limitations. Knowing your enemy well is crucial here.

Comment: Is your proposal are real singleton? Will the instance of this EJB never destroyed during the runtime?

Comment: It's as close to a singleton as you can get in GF 2.1. If in doubt, add logging or other means of verification to `@PostConstruct` to assert that.

Answer (score -1):

Spawning your own threads is strongly discouraged but if you are not using transactions at all and your application actually works, don't worry too much

Comment: thanks Kris. I haven't had a strange behaviour in my application yet. Hopefully it will not change. :)

Comment: "If it works, don't worry" is not good advice on multithreaded code. You should know **precisely** why it works.

Comment: I wrote 'dont worry too much' which doesn't mean not to worry at all